# How do I set a "failsafe" response for my Oscova chatbot?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, chatbot

I'm creating an in-game chatbot in Unity, using Oscova Bot and Oryzer, which is new to me. I've set several expressions and responses to communicate with the chatbot, but I want to set a default/error response when the user input doesn't match any of the expressions.

I'm sure it's a simple solution, but I've tried scouring the documentation and google and can't come up with anything.

Answer (score 0):

`FailSafe` responses come from `Fallback` intents

You can find more information on Fallback intents on the developer portal

https://developer.syn.co.in/tutorial/bot/oscova/fallback-intents.html?tabs=csharp-global-fallback